# How to connect onmousemove with onmousedown?

Tags: javascript, onmousedown, onmousemove

I want to press the mouse button and move the cursor, showing the coordinates of the cursor while the button is pressed. When i stop clicking it should stop showing the coordinates.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 3000px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    document.onmousedown = handleMouseDown;
    function handleMouseDown(event) {
      console.log("down")
    }

    document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
      var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;

      event = event || window.event;
      if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
        eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
        doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
        body = eventDoc.body;

        event.pageX = event.clientX +
          (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
          (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
        event.pageY = event.clientY +
          (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
          (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
      }
      console.log("left: " + event.pageX + "px -- right: " + event.pageY + "px");
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `document.onmousemove && document.onmousedown = handleMouseDown;`

Comment: SImply connect your mouse move handler only on mouse down and disconnect it again on mouse up. So you don't need any extar checks in the mouse move function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attach/detach the `mousemove` handling function upon `mousedown`/`mouseup` events:

```js
document.onmousedown = function () {
    document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
};
document.onmouseup = function () {
    document.onmousemove = null;
};

function handleMouseMove(event) {
  var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;

  event = event || window.event;

  if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
    eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
    doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
    body = eventDoc.body;

    event.pageX = event.clientX +
      (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
      (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
    event.pageY = event.clientY +
      (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
      (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
  }
  console.log("left: " + event.pageX + "px -- right: " + event.pageY + "px");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Problem Soveld!!