# Activating the "onmousemove" event only when the "onmousedown" event is activated

Tags: javascript, css

After discovering the difficulties of styling inputs of type range, I though it best to simply create one using css and hiding the original. I'm trying to Make a volume slider, but I don't think I fully understand how to connect **onmousemove** and **onmousedown**. I tried following the following post

[How to connect onmousemove with onmousedown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903805/how-to-connect-onmousemove-with-onmousedown)

but my **volumeSlider** function - the javascript code that is commented out - still isn't working;

What I want is that **onmousemove** is only activated on **onmousedown** and not by simply moving the mouse.

```js
const volume_div = document.querySelector('.volume');
const volumeBtn_div = document.querySelector('.volume-button');

function volumeClick(event) {
  let x = event.offsetX;
  volume_div.style.width = (Math.floor(x) + 10) + 'px';
}

/*
volumeBtn_div.onmousedown = function() {
  volumeBtn_div.onmousemove = volumeSlide;
};

function volumeSlide(event) {
  let x = event.offsetX;
  volume_div.style.width = Math.floor(x) + 'px';
}*/
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}

.volume-range {
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #555;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.volume-range>.volume {
  height: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #2ecc71;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}

.volume-range>.volume>.volume-button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Volume</title <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="volume-range" onclick="volumeClick(event)">
    <div class="volume">
      <div class="volume-button"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: One approach is to add the mousemove listener on mousedown and remove it on mouseup. I wonder if these properties were written now they'd be "cursormove", "primarybuttondown" and "primarybuttonup"? ;-)

Comment: I'm new to DOM manipulation so I have not met "primarybuttondown" and "primarybuttonup" yet :(.

Comment: It was just speculation, they don't exist (but maybe in parallel reality…).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you could just set a flag onmousedown and reset it onmouseup. Something like:

```
let mouseIsDown = false;
volumeBtn_div.onmousedown = function() { mouseIsDown = true };
volumeBtn_div.onmouseup = function() { mouseIsDown = false };
volumeBtn_div.onmousemove = volumeSlide;
function volumeSlide(event) {
  if(mouseIsDown){
    let x = event.offsetX;
    volume_div.style.width = Math.floor(x) + 'px';
  }
}
```

...

---

In response to your comment, this similar example works in Chrome. I changed the EventListener syntax. It should get you on the right track.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    div { width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="input"></div>
  <p id="output"></p>
  <script>
    const input = document.getElementById("input");
    const output = document.getElementById("output");
    let mouseIsDown = false;
    input.addEventListener("mouseup", up);
    input.addEventListener("mousedown", down);
    input.addEventListener("mousemove", slide);

    function down(){ mouseIsDown = true; }
    function up(){ mouseIsDown = false; }
    function slide(e) {
      if(mouseIsDown){
        var x = e.clientX;
        var pos = "pos: " + x;
        output.innerHTML = pos;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like your solution! you made it seem so simple. However I can't get it to work. Can you please try it in the code snippet?

Comment: the problem is `let x = event.offsetX;` uses the ".volume-button" event and not the "volume" event;

Comment: Thank you for the help. and Of cause I intended to. :)