# Building a custom volume slider

Tags: javascript

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54281842/activating-the-onmousemove-event-only-when-the-onmousedown-event-is-activate) and tried to fix it as the logic behind it is similar to what I'm trying to achieve. I've manage to get it working with minimal editing. but it isn't working as expected.

**note**: I have commented out the click feature as it is working fine.

**What is happening**

1. If you click on the `volumeBtn` and accidentally move the cursor out of the `volumeRange` div height or width while sliding either left or right, the `mouseup` event listener doesn't get executed when you stop clicking the mouse.
2. Like 1, after clicking the `volumeBtn` you cannot drag the `volumeBtn` left or right once it goes outside the `volumeRange' div.
3. There is a flicker from the zeroth position to the desired position.

**What I Want to happen**

1. If you click on the `volumeBtn` then stop clicking the mouse, the `mouseup` event should be executed even if the cursor is no longer on the `volumeRange`.
2. If you click on the `volumeBtn` you should be able to drag the `volumeBtn` left or right even if the cursor is no longer on the `volumeRange`.

```js
    const volume = document.querySelector('.volume');
    const volumeRange = document.querySelector('.volume-range');
    const volumeBtn = document.querySelector('.volume-button');

    // volumeRange.addEventListener("click", volumeClick    );
    //     function volumeClick(event) {
    //         let x = event.offsetX;
    //         volume.style.width = (Math.floor(x) + 10) + 'px';
    //     }



        let mouseIsDown = false;

        volumeBtn.addEventListener("mouseup", up);
        volumeBtn.addEventListener("mousedown", down);
        volumeRange.addEventListener("mousemove", volumeSlide);

        function down(){ mouseIsDown = true; }
        function up(){ mouseIsDown = false; }

        function volumeSlide(event) {
            if (mouseIsDown) {
                let x = event.offsetX;
                console.log(x);
                volume.style.width = Math.floor(x + 10) + 'px';
            }
        }
```

```css
    body {
        background-color: #2a2a2a;
    }

    .volume-range {
        margin-top: 80px;
        height: 5px;
        width: 250px;
        background: #555;
        border-radius: 15px;

    }

    .volume-range>.volume {
        height: 5px;
        width: 50px;
        background: #2ecc71;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        outline: none;
        position: relative;
    }

    .volume-range>.volume>.volume-button {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background: #FFF;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Volume</title <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>
    <div class="volume-range">
        <div class="volume">
            <div class="volume-button"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it doesn't work**

This is working the way you described it because mouse events will only be fired when the mouse is inside the element that have the listeners attached.

An immediate (but not very good) solution to this will be to move the listener for "mouseup" and "mousemove" from the volumeBtn/volumeRange to the window object. This is not very good because if you will later need to remove this element, you should also remove the listeners from the window object.

**Better solution**

It would be better to encapsulate the slider inside another element that will give it some padding, and then put the event listeners on that "container" element. It will still stop moving when you go outside the element, but at least everything is self-contained.

This is shown in the following snippet:

```js
const volume = document.querySelector('.volume');
    const volumeRange = document.querySelector('.volume-range');
    const volumeContainer = document.querySelector('.volume-container');
    const volumeBtn = document.querySelector('.volume-button');

    // volumeRange.addEventListener("click", volumeClick    );
    //     function volumeClick(event) {
    //         let x = event.offsetX;
    //         volume.style.width = (Math.floor(x) + 10) + 'px';
    //     }



        let mouseIsDown = false;

        volumeContainer.addEventListener("mouseup", up);
        volumeBtn.addEventListener("mousedown", down);
        volumeContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", volumeSlide, true);

        function down(){ mouseIsDown = true; }
        function up(){ mouseIsDown = false; }
    
      const volumeRangeWidth = volumeRange.getBoundingClientRect().width; // This will be the volume limit (100%)
        
        function volumeSlide(event) {
            if (mouseIsDown) {
                let x = event.offsetX;
                if (event.target.className == "volume-container") {
                 x = Math.floor(x);
                  if (x < 0) x = 0; // check if it's too low
                  if (x > volumeRangeWidth) x = volumeRangeWidth; // check if it's too high
                  volume.style.width = (x+10) + 'px';
                }
                 
            }
        }
```

```css
body {
        background-color: #2a2a2a;
    }
    
    .volume-container {
      padding: 40px 0px;
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }
    
    .volume-range {
        height: 5px;
        width: 250px;
        background: #555;
        border-radius: 15px;

    }

    .volume-range>.volume {
        height: 5px;
        width: 50px;
        background: #2ecc71;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        outline: none;
        position: relative;
    }

    .volume-range>.volume>.volume-button {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background: #FFF;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Volume</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>
    <div class="volume-container">
      <div class="volume-range">
          <div class="volume">
              <div class="volume-button"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Other problems**

In the fiddle it is also shown how to avoid the volume to go outside the container.